# What are antonyms of multifunctional?

Tags: single-word-requests

If i want to say that a certain tool can only only do one thing then how do i call it? I thought of `unifunctional`,but i don't think it's a real and formal word.

Comment: I guess you are a non-native speaker, but not entirely new here. This is an English language Q&A. Please capitalize the first person singular. No offense.

Comment: How about *single-purpose*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Monofunctional](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=monofunctional&oldid=41892947) is the word you seek. Wiktionary,  which licenses its text under [CC-BY-SA 3.0.](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) terms, primarily defines it as meaning "Having a single function."

In informal contexts, you might term someone or something that can do only one thing as a [one trick pony](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/one-trick-pony).

Comment: Usage-use, the term is almost entirely related to chemistry/medicine.

Comment: Which? mono- or multi-?